# Is it possible to get the root log level of Jboss Server, if custom loggers are used instead of logging service provided by the Server?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x, logback

Following are the requirements,

- multiple modules deployed on JBoss AS 7 with individual logging configuration using `logback.xml`.
- all of them request exclusion of default logging-service provided by the Server, using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Following are observation,

- `log.debug` statements get printed as INFO on Server log(server.log)
- it's because **root level** of custom-logger(`logback.xml`) is set to **DEBUG**

Now questions,

- How can I make, DEBUG statements generated by custom logging statement gets printed with appropriate log level?
- Conversely, is it possible to get log level of Server without using it's logging service?
- In other words, is it possible to achieve uniform log-level configuration across multiple modules that use custom-loggers?

Comment: So you want to use logback as the log manager for you deployments correct? When you say "log.debug statements get printed as INFO" do you mean it looks something like `15:15:42,986 INFO  [stdout] 15:15:42,986 DEBUG`?

Comment: @james-r-perkins
Yes, 

 * I want to use Logback as default log-managers for individual application modules, because I want separate log files for separate modules.

* The code,
`code' log.debug("getting URL for instance requested");  `code`
get printed as 
`code` INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) getting URL for instance requested `code`

Comment: Where is your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` located and is this a WAR or an EAR?

Comment: @ james-r-perkins `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is placed under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.

It is a WAR. Let me know if any other piece of the puzzle is missing.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, sadly I gave up. As, individual loggers have individual configuration file. Hence, I concluded that, it will not be possible to control different independent loggers. I was exploring if we can use Jboss root logger instance for all of them in some way or other.